# Solution architecture

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, clean-architecture

I have 2 API applications inside one visual studio solution.. for customer facing and for an admin dashboard. Customer application is broken into api, application, infrastructure layers... In admin dashboard it's all in one project and has its own authentication and database.. however admin also connects to customer database using the infrastructure and application layers of the customer application.. admin only does few operations using these layers...

My question is, if I'm referring the customer application layers inside admin application for few operations, is it good or bad. Should I instead directly connect to customer applications database directly from admin by creating another dbcontext?

Thanks in advance.

I considered reusability of the code and re used customer applications layers inside the admin application.

Comment: Both answers can be right.... including both. It is a matter of judging and weighting the trade offs while considering making development easier may give the greatest biggest benefit if there is not a clear benefit of one choice over the other for functionality, security or deployment reasons.